# How to give an if-else statement logic to compute the sum of this series using c

Tags: c

Heres the series:
[image: Heres the series]

Note that, when the denominator is even, it adds up to the sum but when the denominator is odd, it first subtracts from the sum then again for the next term, it adds to the sum. For every consecutive term, the power of the numerator will get updated by +2.

I tried computing this, but it just subtracts the term when the denominator is odd, and for the next term it updates the denominator by +1 to an even number.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main() {
    double x, sum = 0;
    int n, factorial = 1;

    // Input values for x and n
    printf("Enter the value of x: ");
    scanf("%lf", &x);
    printf("Enter the value of n: ");
    scanf("%d", &n);

    // Calculate the sum of the series
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        double term = pow(-1, i) * pow(x, 2 * i) / factorial;
        sum += term;
        factorial *= (i+1);
    }

    // Print the result
    printf("The sum of the series is: %.4lf\n", sum);

    return 0;
}
```

This code doesnt add the next term for odd denominato

Comment: I suggest https://oeis.org/A013928 for the denominators.

Comment: The denominator is `1!`, `2!`, `3!` and then `3!` *again*. How should it continue after this?

Comment: I assume the 4th denominator is `4!`, not `3!`.

Comment: Assuming what I mentioned above, you don't need to calculate each element from scratch: you can calculate each element using the previous one and some minimal additional computation. My answer here solves a similar problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71098975/how-to-approximate-hyperbolic-sine-using-its-taylor-series/72926105#72926105.

Comment: If `n` is large enough then simply `return exp(-x*x);`, assuming again it was supposed to be `4!` in the last term

Comment: Starting with (n = 0) `term = 1;` then `term = -term * x * x / n;` assuming there is a ***misprint*** in the question.

Comment: 4th denominator is 3! again, as its odd, first in 3th term it will subtract then in 4th term it will add

Comment: *"4th denominator is 3! again"* What about the 5th and all the others? If they all are 3! then the code should stop multiplying `factorial` by `i + 1`. Also, please, never ever use `pow(-1, i)` to calculate an alternating sign, see Weather Vane comment.

Comment: That's also just ~ exp(-x^2).

Comment: for the 5th it would be 4!, then for the 6th and 7th it will be 5!, the odd one will repeat twice first one with minus(-) and second one with plus(+)

Comment: Suggest that you edit the question adding the explanation about subsequent terms to the question. Don't bury "further information" down in these comments. The given prototype image of the series does not demonstrate whatever it is you are trying to achieve... "_4th denominator is 3! again, as its odd_" What is odd? The `3`? Or that it is the 5th term of the series? Show us; don't try to tell us...

Answer (score 0):

Given the comments, it seems that the wanted series looks like

```
x^0    x^2    x^4    x^6    x^8    x^10   x^12   x^14   
---- - ---- + ---- - ---- + ---- - ---- + ---- - ---- + ...
 1!     1!     2!     3!     3!     4!     5!     5!
```

In the following I'll assume that `n` is the number of terms to be calculated (8 in the previous examples).

The main issue in OP's code is that the factorial is updated at every iteration, while it shouldn't be updated one out of three times.

Besides, calculating separately both it and the powers of `x`, is more prone to numerical errors<sup>1</sup>. It would be better to just *update* the value of `term` at each step.

```
 1    1 * -x^2   -x^2 * -x^2   x^4 * -x^2   -x^6 * -x^2   x^8 * -x^2   -x^10 * -x^2  
--- + -------- + ----------- + ---------- + ----------- + ---------- + ------------ + ...
 1       1          1 * 2         2 * 3          6           6 * 4        24 * 5

                          -x^2     x^4   -x^2     -x^6            x^8   -x^2    
1  +  1 * -x^2  +  -x^2 * ----  +  --- * ----  +  ---- * -x^2  +  --- * ---- + ...
                            2       2     3         6              6      4
         ^^^^^          ^^^^^^         ^^^^^^          ^^^^^^         ^^^^^^
```

The OP could just check the value of `i % 3` inside the loop body and adjust the denominator accordingly.

---

<sup>1) Note that in OP's code `factorial` has type `int` and 13! is already outside the range of a 32-bit integral type.</sup>